# Start pdf viewer in presentation mode

Tags: pdf, viewers

Is there a way to let pdf viewers automatically start in presentation mode?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes there is :)

Simply add this to your preamble

In LaTeX

```
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
```

In ConTeXt

```
\setupinteractionscreen[option=max]
```

Comment: Hmm, with `beamer` it doesn't work for me.

Comment: The command is `FullScreen` (capital S), as @Peter Smit points out in his answer.

Comment: sorry for the typo

Comment: @Matten, I guess you should mention that unless you're using beamer, you need to `\usepackage{hyperref}` for the first version to work... (although why you'd want fullscreen apart from beamer is a mystery...)

Comment: @Hendrik -- if you were using `beamer`, the package should be already used?!

Comment: @Matten: the capital "S" was the problem: My comment was before your edit.

Comment: Is there any PDF reader that supports a [presentation mode like in LibreOffice](http://i.imgur.com/0DjNxeX.png)?

Comment: does @moose's comment appear anywhere as a question? I'd really like to read that answer

Comment: never mind, [found it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/is-there-a-nice-solution-to-get-a-presenter-mode-for-latex-presentations)... but there appears to be no satisfactory answer

Answer (score 14):

Yes, the [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/) package can do this for you.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
```

Comment: If the OP is using beamer, the explicit hyperref call is superfluous: it's automatically loaded...

Comment: It works with Adobe Acrobat but not with other software such as Skim (free software for Mac Os X) or Mac Os X's Preview.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `pdfTeX` primitive `\pdfcatalog` to set up full screen mode directly into the pdf:

```
\pdfcatalog{ /PageMode /FullScreen }
```

Comment: This does not work for me.  Using Beamer version 3.07.  The presentation will typeset, but does not open in presentation mode.