# Is there a nice solution to get a "presenter mode" for Latex presentations?

Tags: beamer

I really like the way Keynote and MS Office (and also OpenOffice & similar) support a presentation mode that displays the current slide, the next (and maybe previous) slide, the elapsed and current time, and also any notes attached to the slides on one screen and the presentation itself on the `beamer`/second screen.

It enables me to give good, professional presentations without having to know everything by heart (I suck at that).

I found a [project which does something similar](https://github.com/jakobwesthoff/Pdf-Presenter-Console), but I am looking for alternatives, especially OS-independent would be great. Not having to create 3 different PDFs is a boon.

Any hints?

Comment: Beamer can place nodes at the second screen if your PDF viewer and OS, I think, supports that. Displaying the time might be possible using a javascript powered text field. See [Having a LaTeX PDF display the date the document was printed, not compiled](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14052/having-a-latex-pdf-display-the-date-the-document-was-printed-not-compiled) to get you started.

Comment: There is no Windows alternative mentioned in the answers. Is there none?

Comment: @BandGap maybe http://freakazoid.teamblind.de/2011/03/30/latex-presentations-with-notes-on-windows-7/ is what you're looking for?

Comment: I think the best solution is a printout with notes and a watch.

Comment: Thanks Z.H. - but that's not what I asked for. I have a specific style of presentation in mind, and messing around with a sheet of paper does not fit that.

Comment: similar question, with a better answer, IMHO: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84622/33322 (the answer is [pdfpc](https://pdfpc.github.io/), of course)

Comment: Mildly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224267/how-to-include-a-preview-of-next-slide-in-beamers-speaker-notes

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I think [pympress](https://github.com/Cimbali/pympress/) comes somewhat close to what you want. As it is written in python, I'd assume that you can run it on any platform -- I know it works under Linux.

If you want to display notes, use
the following to display them on the right:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
hello
\note{say "hello" now}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and then pympress will render only the left or the right half of the pdf in the different windows.

Comment: This is a maintained fork of the original: https://github.com/Cimbali/pympress

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on MacOS. Couldn't successfully install the dependencies.

Comment: Nevermind; managed to get it to work by downloading dependencies with `brew install pygobject3 --with-python3 gtk+3` (from [this link](http://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)), installing `pympress` with `/usr/local/bin/pip3 install pympress`, and setting the library path `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`. Trying to install everything with Anaconda did not work for me. IMO this is the best tool in this thread; thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @LukeDavis May be install xcode tools using 'xcode-select --install'

Comment: pympress works well. The only issue is that I wish to not show "pympress content" on the top of the shared screen

Answer (score 52):

On the mac, you can go with [osx-presentation](http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation/).
(full disclaimer: i am the author).

Workflow:

1. Prepare your beamer `tex` file.
2. Within a `frame`, add presentation notes using the package [`pdfcomment`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment/). For example, `\marginnote{\pdfcomment[icon=note]{Your notes goes here.}}`.
3. Compile the beamer `tex` file with `pdfcomment` package global option `draft` (`\usepackage[draft]{pdfcomment}`) to include the notes (pdf comments). If you want to have a version without notes, compile with `pdfcomment` global option `final`. Check the documentation of `pdfcomment` for more details, https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment/.
4. Open the beamer `pdf` file with osx-presentation. Two windows will show up. One is for presentation view, and the other is for audience.
5. Drag the audience window to the screen that you want to show the slides. Maximize the audience window to full screen. Here, you need to have separate windows for your computer and the external screen. This can be set in the preference of your operating system.
6. Give the talk using the presentation view.

Screenshot:

[image]

Selected features:

- Synchronize your mouse cursor in the presentation view and audience view.
- You can draw with your mouse and erase with keyboard shortcut `e`.

Comparing to other solutions:

- Advantages:

  - Nicer presentation view comparing to `splitshow` and `Skim`.
  - Easy to setup on MacOS comparing to `pympress`. `.dmg` Installer available. Less dependencies.
  - No conversion from PDF to other format.
- Disadvantages:

  - Cannot use beamer built-in `\note{}` to keep note. Need to use `pdfcomment`.
  - Notes are not well wrapped. You either need to use `\textCF` to change line or tweak the Python script for auto-wrapping the notes. For an attempt to tweak the Python script, check https://bitbucket.org/rndblnch/osx-presentation/pull-requests/8 .
  - Hard to generate PDF with nicely formatted notes.
  - Only works for MacOS.

from the website:

> Présentation.app main feature is its presenter view on the main
>   display that shows the current and next slides, and its main view on
>   the secondary display (if present) that shows the current slide. It
>   also has some more or less original features:
>
> - a clock that displays the current time or a (countdown) timer;
> - the content of PDF notes are displayed below the current slide;
> - navigation links inside the PDF do work;
> - external links can be followed, and the main view then toggles to a full screen web view or a video view if the links leads to a video on
>     the local file system;
> - the app is in fact a python script that can be used from the command line.

Demo tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt, t]{beamer}

% draft will print out comment
% final will hide all comment
\usepackage[draft]{pdfcomment}
\newcommand{\pdfnote}[1]{\marginnote{\pdfcomment[icon=note]{#1}}}

\usetheme{default}
\title{Demo of osx-presentation}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Demo of notes}
This is the content of slide. 
\pdfnote{My presentation notes. }
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Another slide to show the next slide feature}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please improve your answer by showing how it works?

Comment: Looks like exactly what I was looking for. Will give it a try at my next lectures...

Comment: @hoeni How did this work out for you?

Comment: Présentation.app is by far the best tool I've seen for this. I'm using it in all my lectures now.

Comment: Amazing. I've been looking for something like this for so long. Thank you so much @rndblnch, works great. Just to let you know, I presented my thesis with présentation. Totally recommended.

Comment: Great stuff. Some formatting would be appreciated though; math formula seems complicated, but wrapping is definitely needed. In your notes you mention `\textCF`, but you meant `\textCR` or `\textLF`. It got me confused, so I thought I'd mention it for the next reader.

Comment: Excellent piece of software!

Comment: This looks very promising, will check it out! Quick tip: Add the screenshot from this post to http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation/ as well. It's so much quicker to get a first impression from a screenshot than just text.

Comment: On mac Catalina apps crashes on start. Very sad. Hopefully it will be fixed, nice app.

Answer (score 22):

Another Mac-specific (well, not really OS-independent) solution is implemented by the [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) PDF viewer, which provides an option to display a second PDF file inside another Window page-synchronously with the first one. This comes quite handy to show beamer notes on a second screen (regardless of its dimensions and layout).

One prerequisite for this to work is, however,  that your `notes.pdf` actually has the same number of pages than `slides.pdf`. With beamer this can be somewhat tricky to achieve, as beamer ships out a notes page only for slides that actually do have notes and only once for frames that use `allowframebreaks`. I had asked about a solution to this problem in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11708/run-macro-on-each-frame-in-beamer), the answer given by Ulrich Schwarz solves it nicely.

Comment: +1 for Skim. And here is my solution to solve the problem of having the same number of pages for slides and notes: generate the main pdf without notes (for presentation) and another pdf **with** notes for local reference :)

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84622/33322), I believe that the [pdfpc](https://pdfpc.github.io) solution is much better than [pympress](https://web.archive.org/web/20140915052129/http://pympress.org/), mainly because it can display notes, but also video and much more. It seems to be better maintained as well.

However, it is a fork of the project mentioned in the original question ([pdf-presenter-console](http://web.archive.org/web/20120313155207/http://westhoffswelt.de/projects/pdf_presenter_console.html), now mostly dead) which means it is pretty Linux-specific (it depends on GTK) for now, although it could probably be ported to Mac and Windows eventually. To be fair, pympress is *also* linux-specific.

Comment: pympress too can display notes (both beamer page and pdf annotations), videos, and much more. :)

Answer (score 14):

If you like the presenter display in Keynote, you can use the free tool **[PDF to Keynote](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/freesoftware/pdftokeynote.html)** to convert your PDF slides to Keynote format, and then use Keynote to give the presentation.

Answer (score 12):

For Linux I found [dspdfviewer](https://github.com/dannyedel/dspdfviewer) to be useful.

> This is a simple viewer for latex-beamer presentations that are built with the show notes on second screen option of latex-beamer.
>
> It will take your PDF file, split it in a left and right half and render the two halves individually to the screens.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Since impressive stopped working correctly for me, this is the best solution available, even better than impressive.

Comment: It is in the package repository, for example on Debian or Ubuntu, dspdfviewer can be installed with `sudo apt-get install dspdfviewer `.

Answer (score 10):

[Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/) gives you at least the elapsed time, and a progress bar which indicates how much time you have left. These are also visible to the audience.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to try out [SlidePilot](https://www.slidepilotapp.com/?utm_source=SO) for macOS.

The application aims to combine two worlds, presenting *LaTex Beamer* PDFs (and its notes) but with the presenter experience of *Keynote*.

Some Key Features:

- Dual Screen presentation
- Presenter Display showing the current, next and notes slide (created with Beamer `\note`)
- Stopwatch or Timer and a Clock to keep track of reading time
- Go-To-Browser for slides
- Broadcast Cursor to presentation screen
- Cover presentation screen
- Pre-Rendering and Caching

With a lot of features still [to come](https://slidepilot.gitbook.io/slidepilot/release-plan).

[image]

Example for a `.tex` file with notes, that you can use with SlidePilot.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}

\frame{
    \frametitle{Demo Slide} 
    Content of the demo slide.
}
\note{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item These are some
        \item items in a list
        \item full of notes
    \end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

(*Disclaimer: I am the developer*)

Comment: This is by far the best and easiest to use. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Benjamin Keller also presented a nice approach [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QLAZEohs1g). It has a presenter view showing

- main slide
- notes
- preview of next slide
- structure tree of slides
- several counters and timers.

Links to the files can be found in the video description. Seems like it was developed on and for Linux. I do not know if other OS are supported as well.

Comment: It looks really great! Imho, PDF + Javascript are cross-OS. Modifying the required settings might however be a bit more tedious on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

On a Mac you can use [Splitshow](https://github.com/mpflanzer/splitshow).

> A tool for the dual-head presentation of PDF slides on Mac OS X, most likely using a laptop and a projector. The project arose out of the need to correctly project slides created with LaTeX's beamer class.
>
> This project has been imported from the original, discotinued Google Code project (http://splitshow.googlecode.com). The aim is to create an up-to-date version of the SplitShow program with the same features and to extend it later on.

Answer (score 3):

I made such an OS-independent web tool for this purpose, called [Beamer Viewer](https://beamerviewer.pacien.org/).

Slides with notes can first be generated in standard Beamer using `\note{}` and `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}`.
This produces a single PDF containing both the speaker's notes and the slides.

This file can then be loaded in the web app,
which opens the notes and slides in two synchronised windows,
free to be moved on different screens.

The tool can be tried [here with demo slides](https://beamerviewer.pacien.org/#file=sample/demo.pdf).
Its source code is available in [this git repository](https://cgit.pacien.net/beamer-viewer/about/).

Privacy note: the slides are fully rendered locally and are never sent to the server.

Answer (score 2):

On GNU/Linux, at least, [Slider](https://github.com/TrilbyWhite/Slider) might be a good option. (I've no idea if it would work on e.g. a Mac.)

Answer (score 2):

On GNU/Linux (KDE), also qpdfpresenterconsole available on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdfpresenter/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/larsrh/qpdfpresenterconsole) (last update till this edit: **2012-03-24**).

- Disadvantages on that:

  - no preview of next slide
  - no possibility to open a Browser and than switch back to the presentation
- Advantages:

  - can handle notes of beamer
  - has a critical time (last 2minutes has a red count down for example)

Answer (score 2):

I use Windows with many animations in my PDFs, and only Adobe Acrobat (Reader) seems to be able to play them. I've been using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) to remap my keyboard buttons to control my two Adobe windows simultaneously. It's a bit of a hack job, and there's no timer, but it works. I use the standard beamer notes pages, but you could be more fancy to show upcoming previews.

Here's my AHK script. It assumes that the focus is on the notes pdf window. [Up]/[Down] controls the notes (window mode on screen one), and [Left]/[Right] controls the presentation (full screen on screen two). [Space] advances both simultaneously by one page. It blocks [Space] in other programs whilst the script's running, but it prevents infinite loops. The script is easily changed to access all open PDFs at once (use 'Adobe' instead of 'Presentation_*.pdf'), but I find it to be more stable if each file is named explicitly.

```
Up::
IfWinActive, Presentation_Notes.pdf ;
{
    Send {PgUp}
}
Else
{
    IfWinActive, Presentation_Presentation ;
    {
        CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
        WinGet, active_id, ID, A        
        WinGet, id, list, Presentation_Notes.pdf,, Program Manager
        Loop, %id%
        {
            this_id := id%A_Index%
            WinActivate, ahk_id %this_id%
            Send {PgUp}
        }
        WinActivate, ahk_id %active_id%
    }
    Else
    {
        Send {Up}
    }
}
return

Down::
IfWinActive, Presentation_Notes.pdf ;
{
    Send {PgDn}
}
Else
{
    IfWinActive, Presentation_Presentation.pdf ;
    {
        CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
        WinGet, active_id, ID, A        
        WinGet, id, list, Presentation_Notes.pdf,, Program Manager
        Loop, %id%
        {
            this_id := id%A_Index%
            WinActivate, ahk_id %this_id%
            Send {PgDn}
        }
        WinActivate, ahk_id %active_id%
    }
    Else
    {
        Send {Down}
    }
}
return

Right::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinActive, Presentation_Notes.pdf ;
{
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    WinGet, active_id, ID, A        
    WinGet, id, list, Presentation_Presentation.pdf,, Program Manager
    Loop, %id%
    {
        this_id := id%A_Index%
        WinActivate, ahk_id %this_id%
        Send {PgDn}
    }
    WinActivate, ahk_id %active_id%
}
Else
{
    Send {Right}
}
return

Left::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinActive, Presentation_Notes.pdf ;
{
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    WinGet, active_id, ID, A
    WinGet, id, list, Presentation_Presentation.pdf,, Program Manager
    Loop, %id%
    {
        this_id := id%A_Index%
        WinActivate, ahk_id %this_id%
        Send {PgUp}
    }
    WinActivate, ahk_id %active_id%
}
Else
{
    Send {Left}
}
return

Space::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinActive, Presentation_Notes.pdf ;
{
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    WinGet, active_id, ID, A      
    WinGet, id, list, Presentation_Presentation.pdf,, Program Manager
    Loop, %id%
    {
        this_id := id%A_Index%
        WinActivate, ahk_id %this_id%
        Send {PgDn}
    }
    WinActivate, ahk_id %active_id%
    Send {PgDn}
}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

For OSX, look at [osx-adobe-beamer](https://github.com/scottsievert/osx-adobe-beamer). It wraps Adobe Reader so it shows the notes and slides on different pages.

It has the following features

> - video/animation
> - notes for current slide
> - on notes, shows current slide
> - <s>timer (i.e., "15 minutes remaining")</s>
> - <s>next slide</s>

In your latex document include

```
\usepackage[slides]{osx-adobe-beamer}
% or 
\usepackage[notes]{osx-adobe-beamer}
```

and copy the resulting PDF so you can display both at once. Open them both in Adobe Reader and run the command

```
python /path/to/present.py
```

And you're all set! If this application fails on you during a presentation, you can still survive because it only maps your keymaps to *both* Adobe Reader windows.

*(disclaimer: I am the developer -- a quick weekend hack!)*