# LaTeX beamer slideshow presentation

Tags: beamer

When I export a `beamer` presentation, I get a .pdf file.  Now I want to present it slide by slide like a powerpoint slideshow presentation, but I'm not sure what the best way to do so is.  I can't find a feature that allows me to open up a slide to fit the whole screen and then click through my presentation with the space bar.  Is there a feature like this somewhere?

P.S.  I looked through [Is there a nice solution to get a "presenter mode" for Latex presentations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/is-there-a-nice-solution-to-get-a-presenter-mode-for-latex-presentations), but this seems too complex (i.e., I just need a "click the space bar to go from one slide to another" kind of advice).

Comment: In Adobe Acrobat simply press <Ctrl>-<L> for the full-screen presentation mode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I can't find a feature that allows me to open up a slide to fit the whole screen

Almost any PDF viewer have in the view menu a "Full Screen Mode", "Presentation mode" or something similar,as well as shortcuts as `Ctrl+L` (Acrobat Reader), `F5` (Evince) or `Crtl+Shift+P` (Okular).Just search in the menu.

But if you want start in this mode to avoid delays in front of the audience, you can use the option `pdfpagemode=FullScreen` of the  `hyperref` package (already loaded by the document class):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\begin{document}
Hello,World
\end{document}
```

This way, assuming that you open the PDF with Acrobat Reader (e.g.:`acroread file.pdf`) it should be showed in the whole screen without `Ctrl+L`, although this and others  viewers as `okular` will ask for confirmation the first time. Others as `xpdf` simply ignore this option. Others as `evince` simply do the job. Others as `impressive` (really a presentation tool, not a simple pdf viewer) show any PDF in full screen mode, with or without this option.

> and then click through my presentation with the space bar.

This is the usual behavior in presentation mode with any PDF viewer (space bar = next page).

Comment: The exported output (.pdf) file is the same with or without this option. Could you please explain?

Comment: @warship. Not really the same. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for the (important) distinction between PDF viewer and presentation tool (like impressive)!

Comment: @Fran I use Preview (I'm on Mac OS X) instead of Acrobat Reader and do not have the `acroread` command in my command line utilities.  In Preview, the `\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}` does not alter the final outcome.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @warship, I have no experience with Mac OS X, but Acrobat Reader is available also for this OS. Moreover, you can try with the many free PDF viewers for Mac (see [here](http://www.iskysoft.com/edit-pdf/pdf-reader-for-mac.html) for example).

Comment: @warship: Preview uses Shift-CMD-F to enter full screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TexMaker 5.0.3(64 bit) there is an eye icon immediately after the zoom out icon. You click that and a drop down menu appears. Click on presentation and it will open in presentation mode.