# Alternatives to tdclock / PDF viewers supporting tdclock

Tags: beamer, tdclock

I tried to use [tdclock package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tdclock?lang=en) to embed a stopwatch in a beamer PDF file.

However, Adobe Reader is the only PDF viewer that can properly display the stopwatch/clock without those empty red boxes.
Nevertheless, Adobe Reader is sluggish and crashes frequently when opening my presentation file.

In addition to embedding a stopwatch/clock, my presentation file has a movie (embedded by `media9` package) which can be properly loaded/played in Adobe Reader and Foxit Reader. 
Unfortunately, Foxit Reader can't load `tdclock` stopwatch/clock and replaces it with empty red boxes despite enabling javascript and marking the file as safe.

My questions are:

1. are there any alternatives to `tdclock` package?
2. is it possible to fix the empty red boxes issue in Foxit Reader?
3. what is the PDF viewer that can properly load `tdclock` clock/stopwatch and play embedded movies flawlessly?

Comment: Would you consider a presenter mode to be an alternative to the stopwatch? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/is-there-a-nice-solution-to-get-a-presenter-mode-for-latex-presentations

Comment: I couldn't open the link http://pympress.org/ . Does it work with you or I have a problem?

Comment: No, it does not work for me either. The source is available at https://github.com/Schnouki/pympress

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321075/beamer-pdf-presentation-viewer-to-play-embedded-videos-and-show-elapsed-time

Comment: @sam I could provide an alternative clock implementation that also works in Foxit Reader and fixes some other `tdclock` issues (red boxes, asking for saving document upon closing).

Comment: @AlexG Sounds interesting. I voted to reopen.

Comment: @AlexG Btw: Interesting that pings with @ sam work!

Comment: It suffices to be unique in the current conversation.

Comment: @samcarter I don't remember why I asked this question,but I think the [other one of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321075/2288) doesn't have such issues.

Comment: @Diaa I tried your other suggestion today again, yet without success. Would you please vote for reopening the question?

Comment: @alexg I think I don't have the privilege to vote for reopen. I am out of home to reproduce your issue. So, I hope someone can help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a stopwatch, but another digital clock implementation showing the wall-time, working out of the box in AR and Foxit.

No empty red boxes in non-conforming PDF viewers, no save-the-changes dialog upon closing the document in AR and Foxit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Digital Clock
%
% Usage:
%
%   % set-up (defaults)
%   \def\clockfont{Helvetica} % or Times
%   \def\clockfontscale{0.93}
%   \def\clockformat{yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:ss}
%   \def\clockrefresh{1000} % milli-seconds
%
%   % insert clock
%   \digiclock
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfbase,xcolor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\clockPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\clockPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\clockAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\def\clock@start#1#2#3{%
  function showtime#3(){%
    this.getField("digiclock.#3").value=util.printd("#1",new Date());%
    this.dirty=false;%
  }%
  try{showtime#3();}catch(e){}%
  try{app.clearInterval(digiclock#3);}catch(e){}%
  try{var digiclock#3=app.setInterval("showtime#3()",#2);}catch(e){}%
}%
\def\clock@stop#1{try{app.clearInterval(digiclock#1);}catch(e){}}%
\newcounter{clock@num}%
\newlength\ex@height%
\newlength\clock@width%
\newlength\clock@height%
\def\digiclock{%
  \settowidth\clock@width{\clockformat}%
  \settoheight\clock@height{\clockformat}%
  \settoheight\ex@height{X}%
  \extractcolorspec{.}\clock@tempb% current color (\setcolor{...})
  \expandafter\convertcolorspec\clock@tempb{rgb}\clock@tempb%
  \edef\clock@tempa{\expandafter\clock@rgbcomp\clock@tempb\@nil}%
  \raisebox{\depth}{%
    \makebox[\clockfontscale\clock@width][l]{%
      \clockPdfAnnot{\clockfontscale\clock@width}%
                    {\clockfontscale\clock@height}{\clockfontscale\clock@height}{%
        /Subtype/Widget/FT/Tx/T (digiclock.\theclock@num) /Ff 1
        /DA (/\clockfont\space 0 Tf \clock@tempa\space rg)
        /MK<</BC []/BG []>>
        /Q 2
        /BS <</W 1/S/S>>
      }%
      \clockAppendToFields{\clockPdfLastAnn}%
      %this is for Foxit compatibility: Widget annots don't seem to acknowledge /P* events;
      %therefore, we move /AA into a separate Screen annot
      \clockPdfAnnot{1ex}{0.5ex}{0.5ex}{%
        /Subtype/Screen/F 2%
        /AA <<%
          /PO <</S/JavaScript/JS(\clock@start{\clockformat}{\clockrefresh}{\theclock@num})>>%
          /PC <</S/JavaScript/JS(\clock@stop{\theclock@num})>>%
        >>%
      }%
    }%
    \vrule width 0pt height 0.5\ex@height depth 0.5\ex@height%
  }%
  \stepcounter{clock@num}%
}
\def\clock@rgbcomp#1,#2,#3\@nil{#1 #2 #3}
\makeatother
%default settings
\def\clockfont{Helvetica}
\def\clockfontscale{0.93}
\def\clockformat{yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:ss}
\def\clockrefresh{1000}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usetheme{Madrid}

%page foot
\date[\def\clockfontscale{1.1}\def\clockformat{HH:MM:ss}\digiclock]{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \Large Current date \& time: \digiclock
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```