# Beamer: PDF presentation viewer to play embedded videos and show elapsed time

Tags: beamer, windows, viewers, media9, tdclock

I have been suffering from finding a PDF presentation viewer for beamer output on Windows that can play embedded videos (by `media9` package) and show the elapsed presentation time.

I have tried the following:

**Adobe Reader with `tdclock` package:**

- **Pros**: plays videos and loads `tdclock` properly
- **Cons**: sluggish and crashes frequently

**Foxit Reader with `tdclock` package:**

- **Pros**: smooth viewer and plays videos
- **Cons**: can't load `tdclock` clock/stopwatch despite enabling javascript

**Impressive:**

- **Pros**: fast and has internal clock
- **Cons**: can't play embedded videos

**Dual-Screen PDF Viewer:**

- **Pros**: very fast, has internal clock and dual screen support
- **Cons**: can't play embedded videos

Is there any other solution that can properly play embedded videos and show elapsed presentation time flawlessly and smoothly on Windows?

---

P.S. when I mean `tdclock` javascript is not loaded, those empty red boxes show up instead of the clock/stopwatch,

[image]

and when embedded video can't be loaded, a white page shows up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured out what made `tdclock` not load properly when using Foxit Reader.

I tried to follow the same way in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150528/2288) to add a clock in the `footline` instead of `headline`. However, it works only in Adobe Reader and failed in Foxit Reader (I don't understand why).

It seemed that the proper way to load `tdclock` clock/stopwatch is to place `\initclock` after `\begin{document}` as said in the [package documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/tdclock/tdclock-doc.pdf) not inside the preamble definition of `headline/footline`.

> 5  Macros
>
> The clock must be initialized with `\initclock`, usually at
>   the beginning of the document, after `\begin{document}`.

Before testing the following MWE in Foxit Reader, make sure you use the last version of free Foxit Reader 8.0.0.624 as of today. After installation, you may need to mark the document file/folder as trusted in `Preferences > Security` and make sure that `javascript` is enabled in `Preferences > Trust Manager`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[font=Times,
timeinterval=30,
timeduration=20,
timewarningfirst=75,
timewarningsecond=90,
colorwarningfirst=blue,
colorwarningsecond=red]{tdclock}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hspace*{2ex}%
    \scriptsize{%
        \cronominutes~-~\tdhours\hspace{0.1ex}:\hspace*{0.5ex}\tdminutes%
    }%
    \hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
    \hspace*{2ex}%
}

\author{Author}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}

    \frame[plain]{\maketitle\initclock}

    \begin{frame}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It seems that Foxit Reader is the best choice for me to smoothly view a presentation with embedded videos and `tdclock` objects.

Comment: Extract from `tdclock` documentation (p.4):  _"The clock must be initialized with `\initclock`, usually at the beginning of the document, **after** `\begin{document}`."_

Comment: Exactly that is what I read to fix my problem. Your comment reminded me to quote it inside the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. So, your sentence about package documentation is ambiguous...

Comment: @DiaaAbidou : Your code doesn't work for me. Can you please provide the complete code, aka MWE ?

Comment: @AlexG, check my MWE. Does it work?

Comment: In AR yes, but not in Foxit-7.3.6.321

Comment: You can try last version of free Foxit Reader 8.0.0.624. After you install it, you may need to mark the document file/folder as trusted in `Security` in `Preferences` and make sure that javascript is enabled in `Trust Manager`.

Comment: Ok. FR-8 works. Nice!

Comment: Tried once more with a fresh Foxit-8 install, adding the file in the trust manager and enabling JavaScript doesn't help. Don't get the clock working.