# How to put this movie (.mp4) in my slide

Tags: beamer, animations, video

The following are related tutorial and articles:

1. [Embedding videos and animations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/embedding-videos-and-animations)
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJPyl9AKhmE

I want to insert a movie in my slide with the following codes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      
  \usecolortheme{default} 
  \usefonttheme{default} 
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}




\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Movie}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{4.2cm}
\begin{block}{A}
\includemovie[autoplay,repeat]%
{4cm}{3cm}{goose.mp4}
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I put the video in the same file of the this latex document.
My video file is:    `MP4 Video (.mp4)`

However, it only shows the following:

[image]

Well, I can open this video; however, I cannot open it in my pdf file.
How to fix it?

Comment: **1st**  This looks more than a Foxit Reader problem rather than a LaTeX problem. **2nd** Have you tried Adobe Reader?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, however it cannot work either. My question then should be is my code correct? I mean does it work in your or others' computer? I have only one computer.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321572/36296 how to configure foxit. "[...] you may need to mark the document file/folder as trusted in `Preferences > Security` and make sure that javascript is enabled in `Preferences > Trust Manager`."

Comment: It should work with `media9`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345433/36296