# Is there a specialized Pdf viewer for Latex-Beamer presentations on windows?

Tags: beamer, windows, presentations

I would like one which would also emulate other features of slideshow of Microsoft Powerpoint.

Comment: any `pdf` viewer is suitable for show `beamer`.  no one can show `beamar` presentation on different way (as far i know). personaly i usually use acrobat reader. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: If you are interested in a 'presenter mode'  like in powerpoint, you might find some useful suggestions here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21777/134144

Comment: You probably want to take a look at **Impressive**
http://impressive.sourceforge.net