# Beamer handouts with only / onslide and notes

Tags: beamer, header-footer, handout

## Question

I want to give a handout for my course (made in beamer). I use Xelatex, but I don't think this is relevant here.

The layout should be a portrait A4 with the slide at the top and a zone with notes at the bottom and page numbering (cf image 1).

Img 1:

[image: What I want]

Here is what I tried

## Tries

### Try 1 : beamer handout class

I tried something like this (minimal example)

The images can be anything (`convert -size 1500x1000 xc:grey a.png` should do the trick to create some quickly).

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{handoutWithNotes}  % from https://github.com/gdiepen/latexbeamer-handoutWithNotes
\pgfpagesuselayout{1 on 1 with notes}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Goettingen}
\usecolortheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \only<1>{\centering \includegraphics[width=10cm]{a.png}}
    \only<2>{\centering \includegraphics[width=10cm]{b.png}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which works nearly fine (cf image 1) where there is no `\only` or \onslide or \pause. But when the slide takes more than one page it doesn't display nicely (cf image 2)...

[image: what I get with the handout mode]

### What I would like with this solution

Getting 2 different pages (ie putting in two frames instead of using `\onslide`), with page numbering would be OK.

Changing `onslide<1>` with `\onslide<1-| handout:1>` (for each frame) seems to do the trick, but I don't get the page numbers and I have to change all the onslide elements... (image 3)

[image]

## Try 2 : includepdf and custom style

I also tried to use `includepdf` (`all.pdf` is for instance the pdf created without the [handout] mode on the previous code)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{blank}},pages=-,landscape=false,frame=true, offset=0 198]{all.pdf}
\end{document}
```

### What I would like

But I don't know how to add the note section (I think by hacking a style and a footer).

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! 1. Could you please add a **full**  minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. 2. Please help me to understand your question right, you expected the result of image 1, but you achived image 2? -- Is this a related question?: [Is there a nice solution to get a presenter mode for Latex presentations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21777/124842)

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question with minimal reproductible code. 
Yes, I want to acheive the result of image 1 but get image 2... 

I don't think they are related, I want to print a handout with some lines under the frames, for them to take some notes, not dsplaying my notes there.

Comment: Perfect edited question(+1). I get the problem and i can reprocude it. At the moment i can't solve your problem (or does `\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1 with notes landscape}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]` help?), hope someone else could help. - Hint: You always could use the `example-image` in an mwe, so use  `\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}` instead of `\includegraphics[width=10cm]{a.png}`.

Comment: Do you need the `handout` document class option? Without your example would automatically produce two pages

Comment: @samcarter without the document, the pdf I get is the slides, not the A4 document I want to give to the students

Comment: @ice3 No, the A4 layout is independent of the document class option `handout`

Comment: @samcarter yes, I see. But without the handout, how can I get the "notes" under the frame and the page numbering at the bottom of the page ?

Comment: @ice3 The notes are under the frame regardless of the `handout` option. The notes are added by the `handoutWithNotes` package and are not connected in any way to the `handout` option. As for the page numbering:  This is a seperate problem, not connected to the use of overlays and handout options. This is just how the layout of the `handoutWithNotes` package is defined. This can be changed, but you should ask this as separate question.

Answer (score 2):

To create separate pages for each overlay, just remove the `handout` beamer option

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{handoutWithNotes}  % from https://github.com/gdiepen/latexbeamer-handoutWithNotes
\pgfpagesuselayout{1 on 1 with notes}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Goettingen}
\usecolortheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \only<1>{\centering \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}}%
    \only<2>{\centering \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-b}}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]