# Which display program in Win 10 support dual-screen presentations for beamer?

Tags: beamer, software

I want display my beamer slides on dual-screen during my presentation in Windows 10. which PDF viewer should I use?

And, is there a portable version of this software, like SumatraPDF ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by dual screen presentations? Something like the Office Presenter mode? Then have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/is-there-a-nice-solution-to-get-a-presenter-mode-for-latex-presentations

Comment: https://github.com/pdfpc/pdfpc

Comment: The duplicate mentioned is HEAVILY biased towards Linux or programs with dependencies (not suited for portability) and provides few answers for native windows presentation. But as this topic is on hold I am answering in these comments For windows users there is of course Acrobat with its limitations For a dedicated beamer solution there is a 2017 fork of dspdfviewer https://github.com/projekter/dspdfviewer also **within limitations** it is possible to use SumatraPDF portable see https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/does-sumatrapdf-support-dual-screen-presentations/2035/4