# Changing fontsize within osx-presentation

Tags: beamer, fontsize

This question is based on the second answer from [Is there a nice solution to get a "presenter mode" for Latex presentations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/is-there-a-nice-solution-to-get-a-presenter-mode-for-latex-presentations) where the author of the answer  wrote a tool called `osx-presentation`.

I am wondering if anywhere is aware of a way to change the font size and font color for the notes?

The LaTeX command to include a note is

```
\marginnote{\pdfcomment[icon=note]{Your notes goes here.}}
```

I tried specifying the size like

```
\marginnote{\pdfcomment[icon=note]{\tiny Your notes goes here.}}
```

and

```
\marginnote{\pdfcomment[icon=note]{\Large Your notes goes here.}}
```

But the size does not appear to be changing. I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong or if there's something specific to `osx-presentation` that requires a different method to change the size?

## Edit 1 (Include a working compilable example)

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beamer Presentation
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (10/11/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

% The Beamer class comes with a number of default slide themes
% which change the colors and layouts of slides. Below this is a list
% of all the themes, uncomment each in turn to see what they look like.

%\usetheme{default}
%\usetheme{AnnArbor}
%\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Bergen}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
%\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usetheme{Goettingen}
%\usetheme{Hannover}
%\usetheme{Ilmenau}
%\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
%\usetheme{Luebeck}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme{Malmoe}
%\usetheme{Marburg}
%\usetheme{Montpellier}
%\usetheme{PaloAlto}
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{Rochester}
%\usetheme{Singapore}
%\usetheme{Szeged}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}

% As well as themes, the Beamer class has a number of color themes
% for any slide theme. Uncomment each of these in turn to see how it
% changes the colors of your current slide theme.

%\usecolortheme{albatross}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\usecolortheme{beetle}
%\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usecolortheme{dolphin}
%\usecolortheme{dove}
%\usecolortheme{fly}
%\usecolortheme{lily}
%\usecolortheme{orchid}
%\usecolortheme{rose}
%\usecolortheme{seagull}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
%\usecolortheme{whale}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% define some useful commands
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[draft]{pdfcomment}

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide

my slide content here

\marginnote{\pdfcomment[icon=note]{\tiny Your notes goes here.}}
\end{frame}

%also tried \marginnote{\pdfcomment[icon=note]{\Large Your notes goes here.}}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you quite right, but it seems you want to change the fontsize of the printed `\pdfcomment`.

You tried to use `\pdfcomment[icon=note]{\tiny Your notes goes here.}`. That does not work, because the used fontsize for displayed pdf comment is set with the class option `fontsize=15bp` of package `pdfcomment`.

As far as I can see you can not change the fontsize with `\tiny` or `\Large`, the documentation of `pdfcomment` does not mention any possibility to do this.

You can also test the line

```
\marginnote{\pdfcomment[icon=note]{\tiny Your notes goes here. \Large Your notes goes here.}
```

to see that are no font size changings in your pdf comment (and no warnings or error messages too)!

You can only define the general fontsize for all pdf comments with class option `fontsize`:

```
\usepackage[fontsize=15bp]{pdfcomment}
```

You can use the following code for testing:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{%
  \usetheme{Berlin}
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
% define some useful commands
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[fontsize=15bp]{pdfcomment}
%\usepackage[draft]{pdfcomment}

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide

my slide content here

\marginnote{\pdfcomment[icon=note]{\tiny Your notes goes here. \Large Your notes goes here.}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you change the line with the `\pdfcomment` to the following

```
\marginnote{\pdfcomment[icon=note]{Your notes goes here. Your notes goes here.}}
```

you will see no differences. So changing the fontsize does not work here ...

Please see that I deleted all the packages you called twice or more and I changed the order of calling the packages ...

Because I can not create an screenshot of the resulting pdf comments I ommited the image for the result :-(

Comment: Thanks. So in your code, is the `\tiny` and `\Large` still needed? I also don't see a difference in the font size for the pdf comments when I change the value in `\usepackage[fontsize=15bp]{pdfcomment}`

Comment: Ahh I see. I changed fontsize, but it didn't seem to work when I opened the pdf in OSX's Preview nor in Adobe Acrobat Professional. I decided to just use the pdf to keynote converter to convert my beamer slides, and then just manually input my comments in Keynote, analogous to PPT.